# "Whoops! Cannot reach User Daemon." when attempting to use NordVPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I'm in China and on Ubuntu 16.04 and have installed NordVPN through apt. When I run `nordvpn login` or `nordvpn X` I just get:

> "Whoops! Cannot reach User Daemon."

I also tried running `nordpnsd` which runs without output and then terminates and then nordvpnud. This runs without output until I try "nordvpn login", at which point it goes:

```
2019/05/30 12:51:49 [Error] rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/nordvpnsd.sock: connect: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're seeing `Daemon is unreachable, is systemd running?` or `Whoops! Cannot reach System Daemon.` your NordVPN daemon isn't currently running.

To start the daemon, and have it also enabled the next time you boot, run:

```
sudo systemctl enable --now nordvpnd.service
```

To just start the daemon once and have it disabled the next time you reboot your system, run:

```
sudo systemctl start nordvpnd
```

Comment: Nope, the daemon service is running without errors. "Whoops! Cannot reach System Daemon."

Comment: @hubro try running `sudo systemctl stop nordvpnd` to stop the daemon, then rerun either of the commands in the answer. I ran into this same issue today and that solved it.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo service nordvpn start`

or

`sudo systemctl start nordvpn`

For me none of the above worked, but they were right that a service was needed so I checked all my services after installing nordvpn `sudo service --status-all` and found `nordvpn` (no d). I'm assuming they changed the name?

Answer (score 1):

NordVPN seems to require two daemons: `nordvpnsd` and `nordvpnud`.
These are provided in the install package and reside in `/usr/bin`.
They are binaries and not scripts, so can't be modified.

The error message probably means that the daemon was not found in the user
context.
The reason is, I believe, that `nordvpnud` is supposed to be run per user.
I would suggest to run it yourself, rather than during startup.

If you wish to run it during startup, use the `chpst -u`:

```
exec nordvpnsd 2&>1
exec chpst -u <user-account> nordvpnud 2&>1
```

As I'm not using NordVPN, I cannot go any further than that.
For more information, see
[this post](https://forum.artixlinux.org/index.php/topic,999.msg0.html).

Comment: I tried running nordpnsd which runs without output and then terminates and then nordvpnud.
This runs without output until I try "nordvpn login", at which point it goes:
2019/05/30 12:51:49 [Error] rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial unix /run/nordvpnsd.sock: connect: no such file or directory"

Comment: If they were started by the boot, you should stop at least nordvpnud before running it under user.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case somebody else has that issue; for me worked adding myself to `nordvpn` group:

```
sudo usermod -aG nordvpn <username>
newgrp nordvpn
```

From: https://www.reddit.com/r/nordvpn/comments/kfewlb/solution_whoops_cannot_reach_system_daemon_after/ggtiq5t/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

`nordvpnd` service was already running.

Answer (score -1):

This error happens when you upgrade your Nordvpn.

Try these steps :

1-stop Nordvpn services

```
sudo systemctl stop nordvpnd
```

2-Enable Nordvpn services :

```
sudo systemctl enable --now nordvpnd
```

3-Start Nordvpn services :

```
sudo systemctl start nordvpnd
```

4-Check Nordvpn Version :

```
nordvpn version
```

If your get this message :

> NordVPN Version 3.11.0

**Everything goes well**
[happy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcIyq.gif)

Answer (score -1):

```bsh
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl enable --now nordvpnd
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl start nordvpnd
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ nordvpn version
Whoops! /run/nordvpn/nordvpnd.sock not found
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).